# Getting error: legacy-install-failure while installing OpenVino

Tags: python, pip, openvino

I keep getting `error: legacy-install-failure` error while installing OpenVino using `pip install openvino-dev[ONNX,tensorflow2]`. I've tried to upgrade and reinstall wheel, setup tool and pip.
Below is the full error:

```
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure

      Encountered error while trying to install package.

      numpy

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs due to unsupported Python version (Python 3.10 is not yet supported by OpenVINO™). OpenVINO™ Toolkit is supported only for Python versions 3.6-3.9 on Windows OS.

Refer to the [System Requirements](https://pypi.org/project/openvino-dev/) for more information.

Comment: after installing python 3.9, it works! Thank you so much